# How to pass variable in find using cakephp and mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp

I have a problem. Before, I was using mysql in my cakephp application. How I search in the database is pretty much easy like:

```
 $user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id)));
```

But when I started using MongoDB, i cannot use $id anymore.

I tried querying:

```
$id = 1;
$user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id)));
// This query wont work

$id = '1';
$user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id)));
// This will work
```

I have to contain a value in apostrophe's. But in my application, I use session variables which does not contain any apostrophe's.

How do I make variables not contain apostrophe's and still make my queries work.

Comment: `$this->set('user',$user);` or `$this->set(compact('user'));`

Comment: `(string)$id` in place of `$id` in the second query will always find by explicit string, however this is probably more down to bad database design that the number is a string.

Comment: Hi Dipesh, its not the $user, its the $id that I'm having problem with. Thanks

Comment: Both should work exactly the same. What type is your id field in the db?

Comment: The first thing is how you are saving the value to MongoDB. I have integrated this by using the id generated by the plugin(MongDB) ( of 24 char long) and its working fine with the code you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have the '_id' instead of normal 'id'.